# How can I make the "login layout" change layout after a successful login

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I am trying to get my login layout to change automatically after I successfully logged in, I didn't find much help, I tried an if else if but it didn't work ...

it's for a background class..

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends  AsyncTask <String,Void,String> {


Context context;
AlertDialog alertDialog;
BackgroundWorker (Context ctx)
{
    context = ctx;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");

}


@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String type = params[0];
    String login_url = "http://192.168.0.40/login.php";
    if(type.equals("login")) {
        try {
            String user_name = params[1];
            String password = params[2];
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name, "UTF-8")+"&"
                              +URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            String result="";
            String line="";
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
                result  += line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    alertDialog.setMessage(result);
    alertDialog.show();

    }
}
```

I've tried in several ways with the if / else if, I still can't find a change in layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your view `public` in your activity class then inside your `onPostExecute(String s)` method type cast your context and update your layout something like this..
`((MainActivity)context).layout.setVisibility(View.Visible);`